# Android Bash script could not work in android application

Tags: android, bash, logcat, android-logcat

I have a log.sh script that contains,

```
!/bin/bash

logcat -d -b main -v time > /sdcard/log.txt
```

it is working on "adb shell sh /sdcard/log.sh" but when i embedded in android application just like,

```
Process        proc;
BufferedReader in;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cgama);

    try
    {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /sdcard/log.sh");

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("gama", e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (proc != null)
        {
            proc.destroy();
            proc = null;
        }


    }
```

What is wrong going on ? Device is not rooted. Device should not be rooted when i do this.Thanks.

Comment: `/sdcard/` if device not rooted then how to access `sdcard` by `root`?

Comment: here is my "ls -al" result.
http://imgup.com/data/images/12348.png

Comment: On recent devices, this will not have permission to pull logs from anything but this app itself - basically you aren't supposed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Change line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/system/bin/sh
```

Comment: Yes, but android does not typically have bash, at least not there, unless the device has been modified.